# Unable to retreive Tomboy Notes from Backup Folder

Tags: backup, tomboy

Due to a software malfunction in Ubuntu 12.04 I was unable to boot up my PC. I backed up the contents on PC hard drive onto an external HD. Then did a complete install upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04. I have downloaded the backup files back onto the PC HD.

I want to retrieve the notes I had created using Tomboy notes. I have located the Tomboy folder where the notes are filed. However when I click on a `.note` file I get an error message:

> **Could not display “2fa83646-81b5-47b9-a9a4-53f45e48199c.note.
>        There is no application installed for “application/x-note type” files. Do you want to search for an application to open this file? "**

I have searched synaptic to see whether there is an addin to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

You can always open notes with any text editor, like Gedit, Ubuntu's default. Just right-click on the .note file then select `Open With Other Application...` and find Gedit.

To get all your notes back and viewable on a fresh install of Ubuntu, you can install Tomboy and then place all the notes you backed up in `.local/share/tomboy` within your home directory. If you can't see the `.local` folder in the file manager, just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden files.